# Scaling with CSS

Tags: css, scale, reddit

I am trying to create a Reddit page using CSS. My problem is scaling. I want to make an object, .side, smaller in length. On my 1080p monitor, it looks great, but when I zoom in or out it will not scale with the browser. It is also too large on mobile.
Here is the code:

```
#header {
    background: url(%%rtv6a%%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -3px 24px;
    height: 130px;
}
#header-bottom-left
{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}

div.side div.spacer:nth-of-type(5)
{
background:url(%%tangoglobe4%%) top center no-repeat;
padding: 250px 0 0;
margin-top: 20px;
}
div.side div.spacer:nth-of-type(5):hover
{
background:url(%%goglobal4%%) top center no-repeat;
padding: 250px 0 0;
margin-top: 20px;
transition: .6s;
}


body, .side, .titlebox form.toggle, .leavemoderator, .icon-menu a, .side .spacer
{
background:url(%%whiteticks%%);
}
.sitetable
{
background:url(%%ticks%%);
}
.morelink .nub
{
display: none;
}
.sitetable
{
max-width: 83%;
border-color: #5C5C5C;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
}
```

Here is what I want it to look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kc33.jpg
When I scale it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ41B.png
You will notice the grey box get farther and father away. What can I do to fix this?
Sorry, I am new to coding.

Comment: gave a link to the website please

Comment: www.reddit.com/r/tangoworldwide

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into media queries:

> Media queries look at the capability of the device, and can be used to
>   check many things, such as:
>
> - width and height of the browser window
> - width and height of the device
> - orientation (is the tablet/phone in landscape or portrait mode?)
> - resolution
> - and much more

You can use media queries to set sizes and widths of text or containers in CSS depending on the size of the browser. Eg:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .facet_sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries